# verbatim text with C code

Tags: context, verbatim, context-mkiv

I'm trying to typeset a lot of C code in the latest ConTeXt (MKIV). It tried:

```
 \startC
    printf("Hello, world\n");
 \stopC
```

only to find that `\startC` macro is undefined. It is defined in verb-c.mkii.
I even tried to put

```
\input verb-c.mkii
```

before using `\startC` but it fails on another undefined macros. What is the proper way to typeset C? The [manual](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_text) recommends `\startC` but it doesn't state how to switch it on except of `\definetyping` (which doesn't hightlight the syntax).

It actually works in MKII version of ConTeXt but it fails in MKIV.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyon

Comment: @Andrew ConTeXt is *very* different from LaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Oops, didn't notice that this was ConTeXt...

Answer (score 3):

This [ConTeXt Garden page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_text#Included_Formatters) lists the [pret-c](http://modules.contextgarden.net/pret-c) module. So the following should work.

```
\installprettytype[C][C]
\definetyping[C][option=C, tab=4] % defines \startC as shortcut for \starttyping[option=C]
\definetype[typeC][option=C, tab=4, style=tt] % defines \typeC
\definecolor[Ccomment][darkblue]

\starttext
bla bla \typeC{int main(){}} bla bla
\startC
int foo = 42;
\stopC
\stoptext
```

Maybe you need to install the module first:

```
tlmgr install context-C-Pretty-Printing
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this works in ConTeXt but in LaTeX I have been using this to include my C++ code. You should be able to change this to work with C as well.

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\definecolor{listinggray}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\lstset{
%backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
tabsize=4,    
%   rulecolor=,
language=[GNU]C++,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    upquote=true, % if true need to use \usepackage{textcomp}
    aboveskip={1.5\baselineskip},
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=false,
    breaklines=true,
    prebreak = \raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
    frame=single,
    numbers=left,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    identifierstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
    commentstyle=\color[rgb]{0.026,0.112,0.095},
    stringstyle=\color[rgb]{0.627,0.126,0.941},
    numberstyle=\color[rgb]{0.205, 0.142, 0.73},
%        \lstdefinestyle{C++}{language=C++,style=numbers}’.
}
\lstset{
backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor},
tabsize=4,
language=C++,
captionpos=b,
tabsize=3,
frame=lines,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\tiny,
numbersep=5pt,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
%  identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
keywordstyle=\color[rgb]{0,0,1},
commentstyle=\color{Green},
stringstyle=\color{red}
}
```

an in the document:

```
\lstinputlisting{\CppCode/SSTe.cpp}
```

Comment: Thanks for the LaTeX answer but the ConTeXt is completely different and it's not LaTeX-compatible.

Comment: Hm, to bad. Here i hoped I could help for once rather than only ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

*DISCLAIMER*: This doesn't answer the question, I misunderstood it and thought the interest was on MkII. As I say at the bottom of the answer I don't know what's the system in MkIV (nor in MkII :D).

Just copying from the link in the contextwiki you shared

```
\input verb-c.mkii

\setupcolors[state=start]
\setuptyping[option=color]

% define the colors to fit your document style
\definecolor[MYcolorone]  [r=.8,g=.5,b=.5]
\definecolor[MYcolortwo]  [r=.8,g=.5,b=.2]
\definecolor[MYcolorthree][r=.8,g=.5,b=.8]
\definecolor[MYcolorfour] [r=.8,g=.2,b=.5]

% define a palete using these four colors
\definepalet[MYcolors]
  [prettyone=MYcolorone,
   prettytwo=MYcolortwo,
   prettythree=MYcolorthree,
   prettyfour=MYcolorfour]

% XML code will be typeset with the palette you just defined
\definepalet[Ccolorpretty] [MYcolors] % the name is magic !

\starttext

\startC
  printf("Hello, world\n");
\stopC

\stoptext
```

[image]

It would be nice to have an official answer from someone that *actually knows* what's the system. Including the way of doing this in MkIV which seems to be the standard now (rather than MkII).

Comment: Thanks for another answer attempt.
Yes, it is possible in mkii but I want to do it in mkiv (that's why i put the flag context-mkiv) and this very example doesn't work with mkiv. It reports undefined \useprettyidentifiers

It looks we still need a solution.

Comment: I thought that flag was a mistake, from the question it seems that you want to use it in MkII. I think it would be better that you state the MkIV part in the question.

Comment: Good point. I added a disclaimer about MKIV in the question.